# Can a Custom Cell Renderer define the properties of an object like a form?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

Can a Custom Cell Renderer define the properties of an object like a form?

I've been looking for a way to define the elements of a `JList` to reflect the current state of an object rather than using simply a string of information. i.e. instead of text use say a radio button, text boxes and labels. In a pre-formatted way like a template.

The items I need to display in a list are time slots for shifts, each one representing a start and finish time and various boolean properties. It would be better if I could use components to show the state of each object so someone could select it. When its selected the editing would be done under the list, not in the list. Just for display.

**Something like this:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MoeQ.png]

Comment: yes cell renderers/editors can use any visualization you want to use, not just text. Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to *render* the swing components inside the JTable cells, then no problem: just return the relevant `JPanel` instances from the cell renderer. However, you might run into issues if you want the contents to be fully fledged interactable `JPanel`s.

The issue, essentially, is this: `JList` (and `JTable`, for reference) use the panel returned from the cell renderer **only** to render the item. Once the render is complete, the instance is discarded. This means that you cannot externally change the state of one of the components you return from a cell renderer and expect it to update in the table.

However, you can get away with it in certain circumstances, because once the user clicks on a cell, the list enters edit mode and at that point the cell being edited by the user does actually contain real instances of swing components, not just renders of them.

I have found it generally better - and even simpler - to use a custom layout manager for tasks like this. An example:

```
static class ListLayout implements LayoutManager {
    private final int myItemHeight;

    public ListLayout(int itemHeight) {
        myItemHeight = itemHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
    }

    @Override
    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
    }

    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        int h = 0;
        int w = 0;
        for (Component c : parent.getComponents()) {
            h += c.getPreferredSize().height;
            w = Math.max(w, c.getPreferredSize().width);
        }
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    } 

    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        int w = 0;
        for (Component c : parent.getComponents()) {
            w = Math.max(w, c.getMinimumSize().width);
        }
        return new Dimension(w, 0);
    }

    public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
        int y = 0;
        // Note: should really deal with parent's border insets here as well
        // Additionally, can add fields like padding, margin, etc. to make this
        // class more generally useful
        for (Component c : parent.getComponents()) {
             c.setBounds(0, y, parent.getWidth(), myItemHeight);
             y += myItemHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

And the calling code:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new ListLayout(25));
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(content);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        content.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(i)));
    }

    frame.setContentPane(scroll);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Of course, doing it this way you do lose additional features of `JList` like selection hilighting, etc. so it all depends on exactly what you want to do. The above will, however, give you fully interactable components in a list-like layout.